# copy a string file and change some text

Tags: java

I am trying to read a file content, then change some inner text, then copy to a new location.

Running this code under java 1.7., the code creates the file but fail to replace the inside content with the newName.

```
if (file.isFile()) {
    Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()), charset);
    content.replaceAll("(?i)" + oldName, newName);
    String newFileName = file.getAbsolutePath().replace(oldName, newName);
    File newFile = new File(newFileName);
    newFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    newFile.createNewFile();
    Files.write(newFile.toPath(), content.getBytes());
}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample input file and what the result should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with that?

```
if (file.isFile()) {
  Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
  String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()), charset);
  content = content.replaceAll("(?i)" + oldName, newName); // Modified here
  String newFileName = file.getAbsolutePath().replace(oldName, newName);
  File newFile = new File(newFileName);
  newFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
  newFile.createNewFile();
  Files.write(newFile.toPath(), content.getBytes());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The string `content` won't be changed by the `replaceAll` function. You have to save it's return value as a new string and use this one.